# public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z)

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

i'm a Beginner with using SFML and trying to run this code
firstly i opened properties of the project then i have followed all instructions in that link https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

this what i have write in debug

```
sfml-main-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
sfml-network-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
```

it shows that error
    LNK1104 cannot open file 'sfml-window-d.lib'

Comment: And where is this file?

Comment: at project folder

Comment: So what compiler are you using, what platform, are you sure you have the lib file at the location pointed by your configuration...

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2015 
and i'm sure of the location :(

Comment: Obviously you missed something because the linker cannot open the file.

Comment: i have checked all thing again but still have the same problem

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) referenced in function _main tortal E:\C++\tortal\tortal\main.obj 1

Comment: it shows that error now

Comment: If you remove the line? Of course, you need to link against the proper libraries. But I don't know your project, I don't know what you configure, I don't know what you have in your folder, I can just tell you that you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501408735894
this is the error list

Comment: if you want to see some file i can send a screen shot so....

Comment: sfml-main-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
sfml-network-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib

Comment: OK, now you see the problem?

Comment: no i don't see any problem :(

Comment: sfml-window  *-d*    .lib not  sfml-window.lib

Comment: i have tried (sfml-window.lib) and (sfml-window-d.lib) and (sfml-window -d .lib) ... but the same problem

Comment: Did you add the correct path to the actual files?